# php://input has no data apache2

Tags: php, reactjs, rest, .htaccess, apache2

I made an api rest for one application but I am now confronted with a problem, the information passed in arguments does not arrive, I do not know where it comes from

my php program is that :

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X- 
Requested-With");

// make sure data is not empty
echo file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
echo $data->user;
echo $data->password;
if(empty($data->user) || empty($data->password)){
    http_response_code(400);
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Error data not found."));
}
?>
```

That return Error data not found and nothing else

My api rest is in a server also containing a react website with a modified route so that it works I did that in my Apache2 config
api folder contain all php files and react is in html folder

```
<Directory /var/www/html/api/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteBase /
       RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(API) [NC]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
       RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

I have not made any other changes, thank you for your help

Edit:
I added three variable display like this

```
var_dump ($ data);
var_dump ($ data-> user);
var_dump ($ data-> password);
```

And this indicates null for all variables
you can try by yourself with this link
http://dev.craphael.fr/api/user.php?user=Osarel&password=test

Edit 2: 
I added

```
var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

and this display

```
string(0) ""
```

Comment: Does the `echo file_get_contents("php://input");` give any output?